# Hash or Sorted set in redis?

Tags: redis, hash, sortedset

I have an use case in my website wherein i am required to store user specific day to day statistics in the form like

```
user:1 {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value}
```

The above representation goes for n users
Currently I have implemented it using sorted sets with fields representing value of the sorted set and value representing score. I am also setting a per day expiry on these keys.

Considering the overhead of individual key creation and expiry when number of users turn out to be large, i am thinking of an alternate representation like below using hashes considering its advantages like the following

```
Map of field1 <user_id, value> 
Map of field2 <user_id, value>
Map of field3 <user_id, value>
Also a map for expiry <user_id, last_updated_time>
```

I am confused whether to persist with the existing implementation or implement the use-case with hashes. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to sort the fields by value, using a sorted set is probably not the best solution for your problem. Using a hash for storing a user field values is definitely more idiomatic.

```
hmset user:1 field1 value1 field2 value2 field3 value3
```

A sorted set could be used to store the expiry dates. The key is the user id, the value the unix timestamp of the expiration date. For user:1 the expiration date will be set to 1234567890 by a command like:

```
zadd expirations 1 1234567890
```

It would allow you to get the list of expired keys for the current time in one operation, using ZRANGEBYSCORE

**UPDATE**

You could use simple keys to store your data:

```
SET user:1:field1 value1
SET user:1:field2 value2
SET user:1:field3 value3
```

It would allow you to let Redis taking care of expiration:
    EXPIRE user:1:field1 
    EXPIRE user:1:field2 
    EXPIRE user:1:field3

Redis algorithm for deleting expired keys wont introduce any noticeable delay. It's certainly better to use it than implementing your own. Look at [EXPIRE documentation](http://redis.io/commands/expire) if you need more details.

You could also use EXPIREAT if you want to specify the expiration date instead of a duration.

Comment: Okay thanks. Also gimme your suggestion on having separate hashes for separate fields? and does expiring a key take a lot of cpu overhead?